# Suzuki Jimny 2009 shaking?

Tags: jeep, suzuki, steering-wheel

I have a Jimny model year 2009. When I get up to 80 km/h, the steering wheel shakes slightly; it does the same when braking from any speed above 80 km/h down to the 80 mark, but much more violently. I've done alignment and balancing, but didn't work. Garage says it may be deformed braking discs...thoughts?

Comment: change the stering shock absorber and then you have youre problem solved. bye.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if the shake becomes worse when you apply the brake, then I'd agree with the garage.  The rotors are wearable items and as they get older, they often develop a warp (or to be more precise according to some schools of thoughts, uneven build up of brake pad material).  How many miles are on those rotors?  Also depends on your driving patterns, my rotors regularly go bad in less than 2 years because the car ends up sitting unused for days and they end up rusting.

The other possibility is bent rim.  If rims are bad, generally no amount of balancing will stop the car from shaking.  Run over any potholes/curbs lately?

Comment: You're right on the money and so was the garage. I had read about worn King Pins and that had me scared, but it turned out to be what you said and it was an easy fix. I still don't understand why it would shake accelerating, if it's a brake problem, but I'm glad it's fixed.

Comment: A severe warping can cause the caliper to move back and forth as it tracks the warped disc, resulting in shaking of the wheel without the brakes being applied.